# Выбор первого родителя в sass

Tags: css, sass, scss

При использовании BEM нужно использовать характерное именование которое в scss достигается таким образом.

```
.navbar{
    &__logo{}
    &__link{}
    &__call{}
}
```

Однако `&` ссылается на своего родителя, а не на корневого из-за чего при более глубокой вложенности получается так:

```
.navbar{
    &__logo{}
    &__anchors {
        &__link{}
    }
    &__call{}
}
```

И на выходе вместо `.navbar__link` мы получаем `.navbar__anchor__link` что не соответствует методологии.

Как сослаться на корневого родителя, а не на своего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ `&` будет заменен на родительский селектор, каким он компилируется в CSS. Это означает, что если у вас есть глубоко вложенное правило, родительский селектор будет полностью вычислен до символа & и подставится вместо него.

Для получения `.navbar__link` используйте:

```
.navbar{
    &__logo{}    
    &__link{}   
    &__call{}
}
```

Для ссылки на корневой можно использовать `@at-root`, ***но не рекомендую***:

```
$class: '.navbar';

#{$class}{
    &__logo{}
    &__anchors {
       @at-root #{$class} { 
        &__link{}
       }
    }
    &__call{}
}
```

На выходе:

```
.navbar__logo {}
.navbar__link {}
.navbar__call {}
```